# Unable to type anything on input fields in dbeaver at Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: ubuntu, dbeaver

I use Dbeaver at Ubuntu 20.04. In some undetermined circumstances I get problem with typing anything inside input fields of dbeaver. I am only able to mouse-click on fields, I can neither use arrows to move over the interface nor type anything inside innput fields with my keyboard. Meanwhile I don't get any problem with other desktop software.
I have this problem with either Java 11 or Java 13. I also tried dbeaver in stable versions 7.1 - 7.3 and in edge versions. In each combination I get this problem but as I said - it occurs without any visible reason. But when it occurs only reinstalling dbeaver helps getting back to normal behavior.

How can I debug this kind of issue to find out where is the problem?
What could be the reason or what is the solution for this issue?

Answer (score 0):

Just happened to me today. I was accidentally running a MySQL procedure that would open over 5k results tab. That would cause Dbeaver to not detect what I was typing. I force reset DBeaver and would still happen. I ended up closing all connections, and try to connect again.  That until DBeaver decides to detect what I was typing.  It took me about 4 tries.  Hopefully it's not an issue for you anymore.

Comment: Hi. I solved it some time ago, but I don't know for sure what was the reason. Nevertheless in my case I had to remove all versions of java and chose one to use. It helped. But, as I read now your case, it might be the problem with the heap memory in JVM. I remember that at the same time I've moved all snap installations to apt installations as well. So one of those two actions helped. Let me know which one helped you.